# How to move up nested list in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I intended this output:

```
columns = ["id","name","col1","col2"]
rows = [10, "foo", "val1", "val2" ]
Enum.zip(columns, rows) |> Enum.into(%{})

=> %{"col1" => "val1", "col2" => "val2", "id" => 10, "name" => "foo"}
```

But unfortunately `rows` is a nested list, for example: `[[10, "foo", "val1", "val2" ]]`, so the code above returns:

```
=> %{"id" => [10, "foo", "val1", "val2"]}
```

How can I access the first element of the inner list?  I tried `rows[0]`, but that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the first item from a list with the kernel function `hd/1`

```
columns = ["id","name","col1","col2"]
rows = [[10, "foo", "val1", "val2" ]]
Enum.zip(columns, hd(rows)) |> Enum.into(%{})
%{"col1" => "val1", "col2" => "val2", "id" => 10, "name" => "foo"}
```

If you have more than one row, you can map over the rows:

```
columns = ["id","name","col1","col2"]
rows = [[10, "foo", "val1", "val2"], [20, "bar", "val3", "val4"]]
Enum.map(rows, &(Enum.zip(columns, &1) |> Enum.into(%{})))
[
  %{"col1" => "val1", "col2" => "val2", "id" => 10, "name" => "foo"},
  %{"col1" => "val3", "col2" => "val4", "id" => 20, "name" => "bar"}
]
```

Comment: It is so nice. I get to love elixir more. Thank you.